# Asynchronous Code not working in expected order in TS

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, dependency-injection, async-await, ionic3

Trying to use a Provider to get data from the firebase server which uses 4-level nested callback functions. Here is how my provider looks like.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var window;

@Injectable()
export class SettingsProvider {

  constructor() {

  }

  public async getFireBaseRemoteConfig(): Promise<any> {
    if (window["FirebasePlugin"]) {
      await window["FirebasePlugin"].fetch(600, async result => {
        // activate the fetched remote config
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //Always "OK"
        await window["FirebasePlugin"].activateFetched( async (bool) => {

          await this.getSliderImageURLs().then((d) => {
            console.log("d", d);
            return d;
          });
        });
      })
    }
  }

  public async getSliderImageURLs(): Promise<any> {

    var urls = [];

    await window["FirebasePlugin"].getValue("slider_images", result => {
      urls = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log("FROM getSliderImageURLs()");
      console.log(urls)
      return Promise.resolve(urls);
    })
  }
}
```

I am expecting the order of execution to be such that the getFireBaseRemoteConfig function returns only when the getSliderImageURLs function gets the data and returns.

According to docs, the functions should be executed in this order:

fetch -> activateFetched -> getValue

In my Page, I am using it like this.

```
console.log(this.settingsProvider.getFireBaseRemoteConfig()); // Just for testing
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: Added Console Log

```
OK
d undefined
FROM getSliderImageURLs()
["","","",""] //this is my URLs array
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. Please review async await usage. For one thing, you are not returning anything in your `getSliderImageUrl`, and does `getValue` returns promise?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, getValue does not return promise. I need to return the value (from the function) that getValue returns.

Comment: can you add your console log?

Comment: @Ben just added the console log. The function at the top is not waiting for the function at the bottom. It finishes its execution before the bottom function returns the actual data that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using traditional promise structures and async/await wrongly together. You can or use Async/await (answer 1 below, but then you have to convert the callbacks to promises) or you can use traditional promises (answer 2), or use the new ionic native firebase plugin (answer 3) which will convert the callbacks to promises for you.

1. **Async/Await structure**

When you use async await, the code will execute like it is synchronous, so there is no need to use .then() in async await. Your code will become something like this.

```
  public async getFireBaseRemoteConfig(): Promise<any> {
        if (window["FirebasePlugin"]) {
          let remoteConfig = await window["FirebasePlugin"].fetch(600);
          let sliderImageUrls = await this.getSliderImageURLs();
          // From here you can do whatever you want with remoteConfig & sliderImageUrls, as they are resolved with async/await
          return sliderImageUrls;
    }

    public async getSliderImageURLs(): Promise<any> {
        let sliderImagesJson = await window["FirebasePlugin"].getValue("slider_images")
        let sliderImages = JSON.parse(sliderImagesJson);
          return Promise.resolve(sliderImages);
        })
      }
```

This method of await/async is only prefered if you chain promises, in your case you chain callbacks. Thus for this answer to work you need to change the callbacks to promises like this:

```
//Convert the fetch Remote Config callback to a promise
  public getRemoteConfig(cacheExpirationSeconds:number=600):Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      window["FirebasePlugin"].fetch(cacheExpirationSeconds,(result) => resolve(result))
    });
  }
```

In your example I would suggest a more traditional promise structure, like the following:

2. **Traditional Promise structure** (without async/await)

   ```
    public getFireBaseRemoteConfig(): Promise<any> {
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     if (window["FirebasePlugin"]) {
       window["FirebasePlugin"].fetch(600, (result) => {
         // activate the fetched remote config
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //Always "OK"
         window["FirebasePlugin"].activateFetched((bool) => {
           this.getSliderImageURLs().then((d) => {
             console.log("d", d);
             resolve(d);
           });
         });
       })
     }
     else {
       reject();
     }
   });
   ```

   }

// getSlider function:

```
 public getSliderImageURLs(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      var urls = [];
      window["FirebasePlugin"].getValue("slider_images", (result) => {
        urls = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log("FROM getSliderImageURLs()");
        console.log(urls)
        resolve(urls);
      });
    });
  }
```

3. **Use Ionic native [firebase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/)**

With the new (currently in beta) firebase native plugin, it already converts the callbacks to promises for you, so you can use answer 1.

Edit: an example to clarify the difference between traditional Promises & sync/await

An example in traditional promise structure:

```
getPrice(currency: string): Promise<number> {
  return this.http.get(this.currentPriceUrl).toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().bpi[currency].rate);
}
```

is the same as this async/away:

```
async getPrice(currency: string): Promise<number> {
  const response = await this.http.get(this.currentPriceUrl).toPromise();
  return response.json().bpi[currency].rate;
}
```

Source of this [example](https://labs.encoded.io/2016/12/08/asyncawait-with-angular/)

Hope this helps

Comment: So it means that executing the `then` function (sometimes with the success callback) and using `await` is the same thing. is that right? We can treat the same object in two different ways, right?

Comment: Yes I will add an example to clarify.

Comment: `getValue()` is a function which accepts two params, the second one being the callback. Can we use await on this as well? I am unsure about this but will surely try this and post back. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: No you can't if you use a callback, but if you rewrite getValue to return a promise like you did on getSliderImageURLs, then you can use async/await, which I would recommend.

Comment: Oh, I can't do that. `getValue()` is part of the Firebase SDK. It works as it works. I can't rewrite it. Same is the case with `fetch` and `activateFetched` functions as well. So this won't work.

Comment: Think I found a way you can, I'll update the original answer to have everything in one place

Comment: That would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Samarth, Did the answer help you out? Especially answer 2 should give you an immediate result. If this answer helped you out in any way, do you mind giving this answer your thumbs up?

Comment: Hey @Ben, thank you very much for all the effort you have put into this answer. I am yet to try these solutions. However, I have tried the Ionic Native solution a few days ago and looks like it has a bug. It does not get the remote config as expected. I will try these solutions tonight and will let you know the results and will sure give a huge thumbs up.

Comment: Glad it helped!